# ¿Cuando utilizar una API y cuando un Web Service?

Tags: java, json, webservice, api

Actualmente me encuentro en un proyecto en el que tengo que realizar un web service o una API, pero al no tener mucho conocimiento de estos no se cual utilizar, el cliente que lo va a utilizar tiene que pasar ciertos parametros y con estos parametros el web service o la api que tengo que realizar tiene que ir a insertar, actualizar y eliminar a una base de datos y dependiendo el resultado del mismo devolver un JSON en el que muestre si las transacciones fueron satisfactorias y si no inserto devolver el error por el cual no pudo insertar.

Lo tengo que realizar con Java.

¡Gracias!

Comment: No veo que exista la alternativa "API o Web Service". Tal como yo comprendo esos términos, una API es un conjunto de funciones que tu servidor ofrece a sus clientes, sin que eso implique ninguna tecnología (protocolo) en particular. Quizás querías decir una API REST. En cuanto a Web Service, en principio significa un servicio invocable mediante protocolos Web (HTTP), por tanto una API REST también sería un tipo de Web Service. A menos que te refieras a usar tecnologías estandarizadas como WS-* (SOAP y familia). Esto es muy complejo y ya un poco obsoleto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;TR (resumen)

Siempre que requieras programar una interfaz para la comunicación entre dos o más sistemas, tendrás una API.

- Un servicio web es una API que se utiliza para la comunicación entre dispositivos electrónicos a través de la web (originalmente con el formato de XML).
- Una API, es una interfaz de programación (que no siempre está expuesta a la web) y no está limitada a un formato para transferencia de datos.

> ¿Cuando utilizar una API y cuando un Web Service?

Cuando la exigencia del negocio lo requiera o tú mismo lo consideres necesario.

[image: API vs Web Service]

#### ¿Qué son los servicios web?

Son recursos informáticos que su principal objetivo es la comunicación entre diferentes equipos y como su nombre lo sugiere; a través de una red.

Dicha comunicación se logra con el uso del formato XML para su transferencia de datos.

#### ¿Qué es una API?

Su acrónimo corresponde al inglés *Application Programming Interface* (Interfaz de Programación de Aplicaciones, en español) y la API una puerta dentro de un sistema que nos permite interactuar con funcionalidades expuestas a través de dicha interfaz.

La comunicación no está limitada a un formato como XML, es libre.

> f. **interfaz** *inform*: Conexión, física o lógica, entre una computadora y el usuario, un dispositivo periférico o un enlace de comunicaciones. — [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Lu1HQaO).

[image: Comunicación entre sistemas - API]

#### Conclusiones

Un servicio web es una API, dado que expone interfaz para dos equipos/sistemas puedan comunicarse, pero siempre y cuando se en XML.

Por otro lado, una API no siempre es un servicio web, dado que ésta no limita su comunicación al formato XML.

**Ejemplifiquemos:**

1. (Interfaz) Para que un estéreo pueda emitir sonido, se envían pulsos a través del cable que conduce a la bocina, pero dicho cable se conecta al estéreo. Dicha conexión (bocina-estéreo) es una interfaz y ha sido fabricada con ciertos estándares industriales que sin garantizará su funcionamiento sin importar el fabricante de la bocina.
2. (Servicio web/API) Un aplicación móvil reporta a un sitio bancario las operaciones que realiza un usuario en tiempo real, su comunicación es través de XML.
3. (API JSON) Otra aplicación se encarga de notificar al usuario del navegador (a través de alertas) sobre las nuevas promociones de una tienda X, dicha comunicación es establecida por formato JSON.
4. (API) Un programador realiza una aplicación de limpieza de datos temporales, caché, etc... para Z sistema operativo, pero también ofrece funcionalidades más avanzadas como recuperación de archivos borrados; para ello, utiliza (a bajo nivel) las funciones que el disco duro le ofrece para lograrlo (interfaz).
5. (Interfaz) JavaScript, CSS y HTML interactúan mutuamente gracias a la interfaz que proporciona el motor de cada navegador web.

---

Si tu comunicación será en JSON, estarás construyendo una API JSON y se le llama API expuesta, si será pública o tendrá acceso desde la web (la palabra «expuesta» no significa que no exista un sistema de control de acceso a nivel lógico).

Si lo que deses es implementar arquitecturas para sobre la comunicación de tus API, te recomiendo veas sobre:

- SOA: Software Oriented Arquitecture.
- ROA: Resource Oriented Arquitecture.
- REST: Respresentational Estate Transfer.

#### Referencias:

- [Web Services, un ejemplo práctico](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb972248.aspx) - Microsoft.
- [APIs versus web services](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/api-dev/apis-versus-web-services/) - Mulesoft.
- [Interfaz de programación de aplicaciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_de_programaci%C3%B3n_de_aplicaciones) - Wikipedia.
- [Servicio web](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servicio_web) - Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Un petición a una API no deja de ser una petición web al uso. Deberás usar peticiones con los verbos (get, put, post, ...) http adecuados dependiendo de lo que vayas hacer en la bbdd. Del lado del backend (API) en vez de retornar un html se retorna un JSON que el cliente puede formatear y maquetar. Puedes generar APIS de muchas maneras, pero yo me inclinaria por Nodejs y Express, para la base de datos suele usarse MongoDB pero esto depende de los datos y sus relaciones, en caso de que sea una aplicación realtime deberías usar Firebase. Además si no es una API abierta y pública tendrás que utilizar middlewares para autenticar usuarios. Si es tu primera vez te aviso que te va ha costar un poco desarrollarlo.

Dices que tiene que ser en java, pero los microservicios son independientes de los clientes. Da igual en que lenguaje este programado el cliente ya que gestionas documentos JSON, yo evitaría usar Java y convencerles de ello. Por lo demás los conceptos de arriba son los mismos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, en realidad no lo voy a consumir en Java, si no que el web service tengo que realizarlo en Java.  Que otros lenguajes me recomendarías  para hacer el web service?

Comment: Herramientas para desarrollar APIs: https://bbvaopen4u.com/es/actualidad/herramientas-para-desarrollar-apis

Comment: Podrías usar Python o Php, pero yo te recomiendo Nodejs (JavaScript)